# Explicit computation $\operatorname{Tor}(M,N)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R=\mathbb{C}[t]/t^2$ the ring of dual numbers. Using the homomorphism $\phi:R \to \mathbb{C}=R/(t)$ we have that $\mathbb{C}$ is a $R$-module, infact we have
$$\psi: \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}[t]/t^2 \to \mathbb{C} $$
taking $\psi(a,b)=a\phi(b)$. So we have that $\mathbb{C}$ is a $R$-module and it is obvious that $R$ is a $R$-module. I'd like to compute $\operatorname{Tor}_i(R,\mathbb{C})$ for all $i \ge 1$. In order to do this I have to find a free resolution of $R$ ($\cdots \to P_1 \to P_0 \to R \to 0$). I think that we can take $P_i=R$:
$$ \cdots \to R \to R\to R \to 0 .$$
If I had taken the correct resolution we have to consider the tensor product $- \otimes_{\mathbb{C}[t]/(t^2)} \mathbb{C}$ and have
$$ R \otimes_{R} \mathbb{C} .$$ 
So I have to calculate the homology of the complex having $\operatorname{Tor}_i(R,\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}$ for all $i \ge 0$. Is it correct? Thanks!

Comment: $R$ is projective, hence flat. So $\operatorname{Tor}_i^R(R,M)=0$ for all $i>0$.

Comment: @egreg I have two questions: 1) What is wrong in my proof? 2) We have that $\mathbb{C}$ is an $R$-module, but it is not flat: $(t) \otimes_{R} \mathbb{C} \ne t \dot \mathbb{C}=0$.

Comment: The fact that $(t)\otimes_R\mathbb{C}\ne0$ doesn't mean that $(t)$ is not flat, but it's irrelevant. If $P$ is a projective module, it has the resolution $0\to P \to 0$, so the Tor with it vanish. What you wrote is *not* in any way a projective resolution of $R$.

Comment: Not, but using the homomorphism $R \to \mathbb{C}=R/(t)$ the field $\mathbb{C}$ is a $R$-module, that is not flat, infact $(t) \otimes_{R} \mathbb{C} \ne 0$... is it wrong?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is not flat as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module; but $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\ne0$. What does flatness have to do with having zero tensor product?

Comment: We have that the flatness holds if and only if $A \otimes B \simeq AB $... We are talking about submodules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For modules over any ring $R$ we have
$$
\operatorname{Tor}_i^R(M,N)=0 \quad(i>0)
$$
whenever either of $M$ and $N$ is flat, in particular projective (or free).

If $M$ is projective, it's quite easy to show: a projective resolution of $M$ is $$\dots\to0\to0\to M\to M\to 0,$$ so removing the last $M$ and tensoring with $N$ gives the complex
$$
\dots\to 0\to 0 \to M\otimes_R N\to 0.
$$
Therefore the homology is zero on all degrees $>0$.

Thus you need nothing else to show that $\operatorname{Tor}_i^R(R,\mathbb{C})=0$ for $i>0$.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I don't understand 1) why $R$ is projective 2) It is well know that a condition of flatness is that $M \otimes N \simeq MN$, so because $\mathbb{C}$ is an $R$-module, it seems not flat because $(t) \otimes_R \mathbb{C} \ne (t) \cdot \mathbb{C} =0$

Comment: @ArthurStuart A ring is *free* as a module over itself. Your remark about the non flatness of $\mathbb{C}$ is completely irrelevant. When *either one* among $M$ and $N$ is flat, then $\operatorname{Tor}_i^R(M,N)=0$.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but is it correct my proof about the not flatness?

Comment: @ArthurStuart You can't conclude that $Rt\otimes\mathbb{C}=0$ from the fact that $t\mathbb{C}=0$. Compare, for example, with $2\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\ne0$.

Comment: Infact I conclude that $Rt \otimes \mathbb{C} \ne 0$...

Comment: Yes... I'm agree with your answer, but I'm looking for $Tor^\mathbb{C}_i(R,\mathbb{C})$, and they can't be zero!

Comment: @ArthurStuart What are you saying? Over a field all Tor functors are zero, because every exact sequence splits.

Comment: No... because $\mathbb{C}$ isn't flat as $R$-module

Comment: @ArthurStuart I can't understand: with $\operatorname{Tor}_i^{\mathbb{C}}(M,N)$ we mean the Tor computed for $\mathbb{C}$-modules; *every* module over $\mathbb{C}$ is flat (also projective and injective, for that matter), so all Tor are zero. If you mean something else, please make it clear.

Comment: If I consider the homomorphism $\mathbb{C}[t]/t^2 \to \mathbb{C} = (\mathbb{C}[t]/t^2)/t$ $\mathbb{C}$ is a $\mathbb{C}[t]/t^2$-module, that is not flat! So $Tor_i^{\mathbb{C}}(R,\mathbb{C})$ cannot be $0$...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11503/discussion-between-egreg-and-arthurstuart)

Comment: My messages aren't in chat

Comment: I'm sorry... I don't find my mistake. $\mathbb{C} \simeq R/tR$ isn't flat over $R$... so it is impossible that $T^{\mathbb{C}}_i(R,\mathbb{C})=0$

Comment: In order to solve the exercize I hevo to find a free (or projective) resolution of $\mathbb{C}$, tensoring and calculate homology...

Comment: Aren't you able to click a link? Here's where you should click on: [**this is the link to the chat**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11503/discussion-between-egreg-and-arthurstuart)

Comment: The chat doesn't work!

Comment: Yes, it does. I give up.

Comment: My question is motivated by this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/564680/edit

Answer (score -1):

Let's denote $\mathbb{C}[t]/t^2$ with $\mathbb{C}[\epsilon]$ and calculate $Tor^\mathbb{C}_i(R,\mathbb{C})$. We have the resolution
$$ \to R \stackrel{\epsilon}{\to} R \stackrel{\epsilon}{\to} R \to \mathbb{C} \to 0 .$$
After tensoring we have 
$$ \to \mathbb{C} \otimes_R R \to \mathbb{C} \otimes_R R \to \cdots $$
we can easily observe that $R \otimes_R \mathbb{C} \simeq \mathbb{C}$, so we have the complex
$$ \cdots \to \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} \to 0 ,$$ where every map is the null homomorphsm. So the homology of this complex is $\mathbb{C}$ in every degree and we can conclude that $Tor^\mathbb{C}_i(R,\mathbb{C}) \simeq \mathbb{C}$ for all $i \ge 1$.

Comment: What's the meaning of $\operatorname{Tor}_i^{\mathbb{C}}$? To me it's the derived functor of ${-}\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}{-}$ and as such it's automatically zero for all modules, since $\mathbb{C}$ is a field.

Comment: no... it isn't my definition. I look it in web.

Comment: I'd use a more authoritative source. You seem to have confused ideas about what a resolution and a derived functor is.

Comment: @egreg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_functor... in order to calculate $Tor$ functor I take a projective resolution of the $R$-modules, tensoring and calculate homology

Comment: Yes, but you have to do it right, not just guess. And if your computation contradicts the general facts I recalled, then your computation is wrong. Please, get a book on homological algebra and use it.